# Rendering different component inside a component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-component

I have 20 different component and twenty buttons.
Component1,Component2,Component3......Component20
button1,button2,button3..........button20
what I want is to render Component1 inside the div when button 1 is clicked and replace it with  Component2 when button 2 is clicked . ???

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {  }
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on here.. but I guess you could have a state that is set by a function like this:

```
setComponent(num){this.setState({componentNumber:num})}
```

and then you check  the `componentNumber` state in the render method using swtich statement and display the relevant component:

```
let componentToDisplay;
//switch statement that sets the componentToDisplay based on the this.state.componentNumber

return ( {componentToDisplay})
```

Something like this I guess...